# zod refine method to allow 2 numbers to be null but if they aren't then compare

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod

I'm making a z.object for a react hook form. I have 2 inputs that are supposed to be numbers but can also be null. Their default value is null. How can I make a refine statement that checks to make sure one number is greater than the other, but only if both numbers are not null.

```
type formData = {
  name: string;
  password: number;
  confirmPassword: number;
  humidity: number | null;
  maxHumidity: number | null;
};

  const schema: ZodType<formData> = z
    .object({
      name: z.string().min(1).max(10),
      password: z.number().min(0).max(10),
      confirmPassword: z.number().min(0).max(10),
      humidity: z.number().min(0).max(10).nullable(),
      maxHumidity: z.number().min(0).max(10).nullable(),
    })
    .refine((data) => data.password > data.confirmPassword, {
      message: "Password must be larger than confirmation password",
      path: ["password"],
    })
    .refine(
      (data) =>
        data.humidity != null &&
        data.maxHumidity != null &&
        data.humidity < data.maxHumidity,
      {
        message: "max humidity must be larger than confirmation password",
        path: ["maxHumidity"],
      }
    );

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<formData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: { humidity: null, maxHumidity: null },
  });
```

In the image it shows that it will always run this validation even when both values are null. The form should accept that both fields can be empty.

[image]

Comment: hint: the default value of input elements is not `null`, so you can't use `null` to check against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refine function doesn't do what you want it to. The refine function body seen above is:

```js
data.humidity != null &&
data.maxHumidity != null &&
data.humidity < data.maxHumidity
```

in the screenshot, it appears that `humidity` is `null` and `maxHumidity` is `null`. So the above expression simplifies to

```
null != null &&
null != null &&
null < null
```

the first `null != null` makes the return falsey.

What you probably want is:

```
data.humidity == null ||
data.maxHumidity == null ||
data.humidity < data.maxHumidity
```

If either `humidity` or `maxHumidity` (or both) are null, this returns true, which passes validation. If both values are non-null it validates that `humidity` is less than `maxHumidity`.